# synapse and https 500 error

Tags: https, get, apache-synapse

There was a problem with the passage of authorization on the site https://www.google.com for receiving data.

I use synapse HTTPSend. Connection I do as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject); 
var  httpsend: httpsend;

begin  httpsend := Thttpsend.Create;
httpsend.Sock.CreateWithSSL(TSSLOpenSSL);  
httpsend.Sock.SSLDoConnect;  
httpsend.HTTPMethod('GET', 'https://www.google.com');  
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(httpsend.Document);       
Memo1.Lines.Add(httpsend.ResultCode.ToString);
end;
```